# difference between i wish with 'would' and 'past'

Tags: grammar

How do the two sentences differ in sense when we say,

> 'I wish it weren't raining.' and 
> 'I wish it wouldn't be raining.'

Answer (score 1):

Sentence #1 is how we normally express it. Sentence #2 is less idiomatic.

Sentence #1 is a good use of the **subjunctive**.  [We use the subjunctive when expressing a hypothetical or a desire](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive):

> If I were king...
>   If only that were true!
>   I wish you could be here.

Sentence #2 is understandable but not how we would normally express a desire that it not be raining.  It works if you use it in a context like "I wish that it wouldn't be raining *every time we arrive at the campground*", because the use of the present continuous *be raining* implies a current, ongoing event, but even there it's simpler and easier to just say "I wish it *weren't raining* every time we arrive at the campground."